# Insertion in one array effects other array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have  2 `NSMutableArray`.I am adding custom class objects into them. I have initialized them as below.

```
 arr_post=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 copy_arr_user_post=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

I am adding the objects into them like this.

```
for(i=0;i<[arr_main count];i++)
{
    Post *obj=[[Post alloc]init];
    obj.name=@"abc";
    obj.gender=@"male";
   [arr_post addObject:obj];
   [copy_arr_user_post addObject:obj];

}
```

Now when i remove object from `arr_post` & insert again then it is also effected in another array.

```
Post *post=[arr_post objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[arr_post removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
post.name=@"def";
[arr_post addObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

then `def` is also added in second array.

Comment: There is no need of removing and adding again an object just to update it's property.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how arrays work.

Arrays store *references* to objects, not the objects themselves. Its a bit like keeping people's phone numbers. If I have a list of 10 phone numbers and you have the same list of phone numbers, and the person at index 1 in my list moves to a new address, when you call your person at index one and ask for their address they will give you the changed address too.

Both arrays point to the same objects.

If you change settings on one of your objects, you will see those changes if you look up the object in either array.

If you want your arrays to contain independent objects then implement NSCopying in your custom class and use code like this:

```
for(i=0;i<[arr_main count];i++)
{
  Post *obj=[[Post alloc]init];
  obj.name=@"abc";
  obj.gender=@"male";
  [arr_post addObject:obj];
  Post objectCopy = [obj copy]; //create a copy of our object
  [copy_arr_user_post addObject: objectCopy]; //insert copy into other array
}
```

But again, to do that you need to teach your custom Post class to conform to the `NSCopying` protocol so it understands the `copy` message. Take a look at the docs on the `NSCopying` protocol for more information.

Comment: I am from java.In java this thing will work.I was not aware of Objective C in this case

Comment: NSArray saves objects by reference. Your custom objects are also a reference type. The same thing would happen in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does affect the other array because both arrays contain the same (identical) object.

In Objective-C objects are reference types. That means a pointer is stored in the arrays respectively which points to the same object.

If you want to have different objects you have to copy them for example

```
[copy_arr_user_post addObject:[obj copy]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because arrays store pointers to the data not the actual data. 
if you want to have two different copies of an object you can use this method:

```
for(i=0;i<[arr_main count];i++)
{
    Post *obj=[[Post alloc]init];
    obj.name=@"abc";
    obj.gender=@"male";
    NSData* objectData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: obj];
    Post* obj2= [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: objectData];
   [arr_post addObject:obj];
   [copy_arr_user_post addObject:obj2];

}
```

OR you can simply declare two objects:

```
for(i=0;i<[arr_main count];i++)
{
    Post *obj1=[[Post alloc]init];
    Post *obj2=[[Post alloc]init];
    obj1.name=@"abc";
    obj1.gender=@"male";
    obj2.name=@"abc";
    obj2.gender=@"male";
   [arr_post addObject:obj1];
   [copy_arr_user_post addObject:obj2];

}
```

Comment: How did you know about this array behaviour.Can you give me reference so i can learn better

Comment: the array behaviour is because it uses pointers which is the address of the data..
you can find more info about NSKeyedArchiver:

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html

Comment: this is not happned in java

Comment: using archivedDataWithRootObject you can store actual data of any object (which we has its pointer) and with unarchiveObjectWithData you can get the stored data and put it in another object

Comment: I am not sure about java but arrays in some languages store actual data and some store pointers to actual data. if the array store actual data you should set the max number of array object when you are declaring the array.
something like:
int[] myArray = new int[10];